# Edit and update a shared feature layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, crowdsourcing, shared-hosting

I am currently shifting to QGIS from ArcGIS. I know that ArcGIS has this distributed collaboration system which allows multiple users to edit a shared GIS file (after uploading to an ArcGIS portal) simultaneously. I wonder if there are any similar features or plugins available in QGIS.

Comment: Not that I know, but you may benefit from any version control system such as [git](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Using Git sounds that users need to constantly commit, merge, and push the changes in addition to doing the editing work. I was wondering if the versioning setup can happen in the database like ArcGIS enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Kart](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/kart/) plugin, it works like Git, but dramatically simplifies the process. The last QGIS Open Day had a nice introductory talk that you can view here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aABc3JrgJUY.

Otherwise setting up an online PostGIS database is fairly straightforward, which can then be added as a "live" layer in QGIS. There is also a versioning plugin for this (though I haven't used it): [versioning plug in](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_versioning/)